# The exact nuance of てもらう vs くれる

Tags: sentence, giving-and-receiving

学生時代　部の友達教えてもらってね

Does it mean more "a friend taught me" or is more like "I had a friend teach me"?

And what happened if switched with てくれる?

Answer (score 4):

A particle is missing in that sentence.

> 学生時代　部の友達**に**教えてもらってね

This に is not usually omitted.

It means a friend taught the speaker and the speaker is grateful. It doesn't say whether the speaker asked the friend to teach them.

The difference between もらう and くれる is syntactic. With くれる the giver is the subject.

> 学生時代　部の友達**が**教えてくれてね

It doesn't say whether the speaker asked the friend to teach them, either.

Comment: but wouldn't 学生時代　部の友達に教えてもらう Mean "I'll have him teach me"?